# Jekyll site that worked well on Local doens't show up on Github Pages

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages

I did the follings:

1. made my username.github.io repo
2. cloned that repo to my local folder
3. In local folder, I did "jekyll new ..." to generate jekyll things
4. I modified "Gemfile" and "_config.yml" to use a theme named "minimal-mistakes"
   (added a line `gem "minimal-mistakes-jekyll"` to my Gemfile and "bundle install", then
   modified "_config.yml" to contain `theme: minimal-mistakes-jekyll`, then "bundle update")
5. typed "bundle exec jekyll serve" on terminal, go to localhost:4000, then my simple jekyll site showed up

---

Then I pushed the local's change to remote server, and hoped my jekyll site show up when I enter my "username.github.io", but when I enter, the page is blank. nothing.

Well, is this because In local, I installed things by "bundle install" or "bundle update", but the github doesn't install things for me automatically?

How can make my username.githhub.io to show a theme-installed page?

+1 question:
I did "jekyll new ...", in order to generate Gemfile and other jekyll related files, but this seems unnecessary. Just making a directory and make Gemfile and _config.yml file inside the dir by myself would work?

Comment: Can you show your `Gemfile` and `_config.yml`? Also what's the folder structure you  pushed to GitHub like?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I know why.

https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-a-jekyll-theme-to-your-github-pages-site#adding-a-jekyll-theme-in-your-sites-_configyml-file
looking at #4, there are github-pages-supported themes and other themes that are not supported. for those not supported, you have to write `remote-theme: ...` to _config.yml, not `theme: ...`

> Well, is this because In local, I installed things by "bundle install" or "bundle update", but the github doesn't install things for me automatically?

I think what I guessed is right.